# Random Image and Classification with p5.js, TensorFlow and MobileNet

Tags: tensorflow, button, classification, display, mobilenet

I'm asking for help from the community because I'm stuck with my code.
For a project I need to create an **image classification** program on P5.js using **MobileNet and TensorFlow**.

I wanted to know how to create a **button** that randomly displays an image (among the 3 I downloaded) with the MobileNet classification below the image and the information I gave (like "Danger")?

[Result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zVv7.jpg)

Here is what i've already done. Thank you :)

```
    var model_mobilenet;
    var loaded;
    
    
    function setup() {
      createCanvas(400, 300);
      mobilenet.load().then(modelLoaded);
    
      military = loadImage('military');
      rifle = loadImage('rifle');
      revolver = loadImage('revolver');
      
      createButton("Take a picture").mousePressed(btnClicked);
    }
    
    function classifyDone(res) {
      print(res);
      if (res[0].className == "rifle")
      {
      print("Danger");
      createP("Danger");
      }
      
      else if (res[0].className == "revolver, six-gun, six-shooter")
      {
      print("Danger");
      createP("Danger");
      }
      else if (res[0].className == "military uniform")
      {
        print("Not sure about this one");
        createP("Not sure about this one");
      }
      else {
        print("Evrything is okay");
        createP("Everything is okay");
      }
    }
    
    function modelLoaded(net) {
      model_mobilenet = net;
      loaded = true;
      print("Model loaded");
    }
    
    function btnClicked() {
      
    image(military, 0, 0, 400, 300);
      
    if (loaded == true)
    {
    model_mobilenet.classify(military.elt).then(classifyDone);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming the MobileNet part works, you simply need to store your 3 images in an array, then select a random image from the array. you can write a separate basic sketch that does just that: loads 3 images, stores them in an array, use [`random()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random) which in p5. conveniently allows you pass an array (e.g. `let images = [military, rifle, revolver]; console.log(random(images));`. Check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233447/p5js-image-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var model_mobilenet;
var loaded;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 300);
  mobilenet.load().then(modelLoaded);

  revolver = loadImage('revolver.jpg');
  baseball = loadImage('baseball.jpg');
  rifle = loadImage('rifle.jpg');

  
  createButton("DANGER OR NOT?").mousePressed(btnClicked);
}

function classifyDone(res) {
  print(res);
  
  createP("Model detected a <b>" + res[0].className + "</b> with a confidence of <b>" + res[0].probability + "</b>");
  if (res[0].className =="assault rifle, assault gun")
  
  { createP("<b>Danger, find a shelter, quickly !</b>");}
  
  else if (res[0].className == "revolver, six-gun, six-shooter")
 
  { createP("<b>Danger, find a shelter, quickly !</b>");}

  else {   createP("Everything is okay");  }
}

/* if ($(".revolver, six-gun, six-shooter").css('font-color: red')){
$(".assault rifle, assault gun").css('font-color: green'); */

function modelLoaded(net) {
  model_mobilenet = net;
  loaded = true;
  print("Model loaded");
}

function btnClicked() {
 
let randomNumber = Math.random()
if(randomNumber<0.3)
{
  image(baseball, 0, 0, 400, 300);
model_mobilenet.classify(baseball.canvas).then(classifyDone);
  }
else if (randomNumber<0.6)
{
    image(rifle, 0, 0, 400, 300);
model_mobilenet.classify(rifle.canvas).then(classifyDone);
  }
  else 
{
    image(revolver, 0, 0, 400, 300); 
model_mobilenet.classify(revolver.canvas).then(classifyDone);
  }
}
```

> Here is the result I obtained. It's not really great but with a little more CSS, it can be satisfying. Feel free to ask me for more details. Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G71UR.jpg).